# Django rest framework queryset custom permissions

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I would like to set custom permissions with django guardian on my django rest framework views. I've successfuly achieved it for `RetrieveModelMixin`, but not for `ListModelMixin`.

I have a permission class looking like this one :

```
class CustomPerm(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, object):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if object.public is True:
                return True

            if object.user.is_staff is True:
                return True

            if 'read_object' in get_perms(request.user, object):
                return True

            return False

        if request.method == 'POST':
            #...
```

I also simplified the view here :

```
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((CustomPerm,))
class ObjectView(ListModelMixin,
                 RetrieveModelMixin,
                 viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = myObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
```

Behaviour I was naïvly expecting : `ListModelMixin` could filter by itself objects according to CustomPerm `has_object_permission` rules.

But it does not work like that. I'm able to do what I want by writing a `get_queryset` method and applying my custom permission rules, but it seems unappropriate and awful.

Is there a better way ? Thanks :)

PS: I'm sure I'm missing something and my question is naïve but I can't see what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that the framework doesn't work that way ... The permissions are there to deny the access (when a condition is met), but not to filter the objects for you. If you need to return specific objects, then you need to filter them in the view (queryset) depending on the current user, if needed.

Comment: I've implemented a solution based on filters and which uses permissions as you described and this is what I needed. I just had a problem with "permission" semantics but it's ok now. Thx both of you :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well overriding isn't awful depending on how you do it... but it is not the question.

If I understand well what you want to do is to filter your queryset using your custom permission.

What I recommend, to keep your code explicit and simple, override your backend filter like in the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering)

But be careful `filter_queryset` apply on both `retrieve` and `list` methods